# How to pass a React component (or raw html) into other React component and insert it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have raw html markup returned from ajax. Rendering raw html is not easy in React. I tried to use their `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` up and down but no go, only errors are thrown from React. That `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is truly obscure.

So I decided to compile my raw html to a React component and insert it. Raw html is compiled to React component all right but I cannot insert it. Here is my code. I want to pass `<Html />` component (or raw html would be even better) to `<Tr />` component as `this.props.b`:

```
var FooComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
            var Html = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                    return (
                        myRawHtmlMarkup
                    );
                }
            });

        return (
            <Tr id={key} a={value} b={Html} />
        );
    }
});
```

Now how to insert either raw html or `<Html />` into DOM `<td>` element? Using `{this.props.b}` doesn't work.

And the inportant thing here is that I cannot change `this.props.b` to smth else like `this.props.child`, `this.props.children`, etc. I need that `this.props.b` because there is a loop in parent `FooComponent` component and I assign values to `this.props.b` using many `if/else` conditions (not shown above for the sake of simplicity):

```
var Tr = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td className="idCol">{this.props.id}</td>
                <td className="aCol">{this.props.a}</td>
                <td className="bCol">{this.props.b}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: How did you try to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? What errors were you getting?

Answer (score 2):

The `render` method in your `Html` component will throw an error, because a component needs to return a valid `ReactComponent`, not a string.

I think you could parse the HTML and append as children in `componentDidMount`: https://jsfiddle.net/4z13gp7g/

```
var Tr = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = this.props.b;
    this.refs.b.appendChild( div.firstChild )
  },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td className="idCol">{this.props.id}</td>
                <td className="aCol">{this.props.a}</td>
                <td className="bCol" ref="b"></td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <Tr id="key" a="value" b="<p><strong>Hi</strong></p>" />,
   document.querySelector('table tbody')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a react class for Html var?

If not, try this:

```
var FooComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var Html = (myRawHtmlMarkup);

        return (
            <Tr id={key} a={value} b={Html} />
        );
    }
});
```